# Whom did Cain marry according to Genesis?

Tags: genesis

According to Genesis, God created Adam and Eve.

They disobeyed God and as a result, they were driven out from heaven.

They had two sons, Cain and Abel.

Cain killed Abel and God punishes Cain.

After that, it says that Cain married.

But whom did he marry?

> And Cain knew his wife; and she conceived, and bare Enoch: and he builded a city, and called the name of the city, after the name of his son, Enoch.
>
> Genesis 4:17 (KJV)

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423) Be sure to [properly cite the text](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/810/423) you're asking about. The chapter and verse numbers do not always line up between the Hebrew, Greek, and English texts. To clarify, are you asking *who* Cain married? Or are you asking something else? This is not clear.

Comment: I edited the post
Is it ok now?

Comment: @MidhunVarghese yes it is, thanks! (and +1)

Comment: Sorry, but I just realized that this has already been asked before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Whom did Cain marry according to Genesis?

According to Genesis, we are not told whom Cain married. However, according to logic, Cain married a daughter of Adam; cf. Genesis 5:4.

Comment: Cain was banished from Eden by God. ref. Genesis 4: 14 'Behold thou hast driven me out this day' God banished Cain which means that he could not go back to his former habitation. Adam respected God's ordinances. Therefore Cain did not return to find a wife in the camp of Adam and Eve. The only clue we have is that Cain's wife was an inhabitant of the land of Nod which is the place to which Cain went.

Comment: According to Logic Cain did not marry a daughter of Adam. To do this would be to deny that Cain's banishment was complete and also to say that God changed his mind.

Comment: God does not change