# Question pertains to Cain's wife in book of genesis

Tags: genesis

Where did cain's wife come from and what was her generations?and

Comment: See [Who did Cain marry?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/who-did-cain-marry) and [Whom did Cain marry ?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8511/whom-did-cain-marry-according-to-genesis?noredirect=1&lq=1) etc etc etc

Answer (score 0):

In the Book of Jubilees she is called Awan; however, in other Abrahamic texts she is called Jumelia. Similarly, her sister Azura (עֲצֻרָה atzurah "restraint") was the wife of Cain's two brothers: Abel and after Abel's murder, Seth. In one Hebrew chronological work, she is called Balbira.

Comment: Welcome to BH. Answers need to be supported by (usually linked) references in order to be considered substantial, rather than opinions.